# check if site available through ip via php

Tags: php, ip

was hoping you could help me out.

I am trying to check if a site(actually multiple sites, put I can do that part my self :p ) is online or offline via their IP address. Ive searched a bit and found out two methods to do this

- using the ping command via exec()
- using fsockopen()

wanted to know which was the better, and more reliable method. or is there another method that I am missing?

I read that using the curl library was the best method, but I couldnt figure out how to make that work with an IP address (and not a link). also, i'd rather not use a library that isnt pre-installed unless it makes a big difference.

Comment: You mean to check whether httpd/apache is running on a given IP? If so  then curl should solve your issues. You can use php `curl_getinfo` to get the status and many awesome details. You can use IP addresses in curl lib. Try `curl 'http://127.0.0.1'` it should work in your local incase any webserver listening on 80

Comment: btw curl accepts urls like [http://64.34.119.12](http://64.34.119.12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by "online".  Ping will tell you if there is a host with the given IP address which responds to ping requests (most do, but some are configured not to.  Or there might be an unhelpful router somewhere in between you and the host which doesn't pass on the packets)

Something like curl will be more useful if you actually want to know whether the host is a functioning HTTP server.  You could check the returned status is 200 for example.

Comment: hmm, thanks. that explains curl and ping, what about fsockopen?

Comment: you could use fsockopen, but you have to format the HTTP request and parse the response yourself. Not hard, but why reinvent the wheel?